# Azure Pipelines workitem status set as variable

Tags: xml, powershell, variables, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a case as below, I want my pipeline to automatically pickup a work item state as variable..and then I want to replace the variable value in the xml file

How to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried, Where are the examples? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: To replace the variable value in XML file, you could have a try with [File transforms and variable substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xml-variable-substitution) or use  [File Transform task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops), [replace token extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run a PowerShell task in pipeline to pickup a work item state by invoking REST API : [Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP). In the YAML snippet, assign the work item state to `$State`, then, add a pipeline variable `Myvarl` with the value of `$State` by using `task.setvariable` logging command.

```
- powershell: |
   $url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organizationName}/{projectName}/_apis/wit/workitems/{workItemID}?api-version=6.0"
   $Token = "{PAT}"
   $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($Token)"))
   $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get
   $State = $response.fields.'System.State'
   Write-Host  $State
   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Myvarl;]$State" 
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

Install [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) extension for your organization and use this task to replace the value of `Myvarl` in the XML file by the `$Myvarl` variable in this pipeline job.

```
- task: replacetokens@5
  inputs:
    targetFiles: '*.xml'
    encoding: 'auto'
    tokenPattern: 'custom'
    tokenPrefix: '#{'
    tokenSuffix: '}#'
    writeBOM: true
    actionOnMissing: 'warn'
    keepToken: false
    actionOnNoFiles: 'continue'
    enableTransforms: false
    inlineVariables: '$(Parameters.inlineVariables)'
    enableRecursion: false
    useLegacyPattern: false
    enableTelemetry: true
```

[image]